# Latest git tag not recognized when installing requirements.txt

Tags: python, git, setuptools, setup.py, distutils

I have a dependency in my requirements.txt that comes from another git repo (not mine, but I have access to it).

Yesterday I merged a PR and after applied the tag v0.1.5 to it. In sequence I updated my projects requirements to:

```
git+https://HASH@github.com/repowner/dependency_name.git@v0.1.5
```

The dependency installed with no issues. However I spotted a bug and decided to fix it. I created a new branch, changed the version in the `setup.py`,  assigned the tag v0.1.5b, and used `git push` and `git push --tags`, all before merging. (I assumed this was the right way to do it, instead of applying it later)

Now I updated my requirements to

```
git+https://HASH@github.com/repowner/dependency_name.git@v0.1.5b
```

However the version v.0.1.5 is the one getting installed when I execute `pip install -r requirements.txt`. It doesn't raise any error, it simple ignores the b in the end. I tried to assign the tag into master by using `git tag -a v0.1.5b <commit_hash>` but I get the return:

```
fatal: tag 'v0.1.5b' already exists
```

If I try to just push the tags:

```
Everything up-to-date
```

I'm not sure if I wasn't supposed to use the 'b' in the version or there is something else I might have missed? Can someone help me fix it? It would be nice if I can solve it without pushing another commit, (like a v.0.1.6) but I take any solution tbh.

Comment: Never worked with pip and requirements before, but this smells like a bug a mile away or a non-supported naming convention. According to [PEP 440](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#version-scheme): `Local version labels MUST start and end with an ASCII letter or digit.`, so I guess you're allowed to use letters in the end even tho I rarely see it. But `[N!]N(.N)*[{a|b|rc}N][.postN][.devN]` indicates that it should be named `v0.1.5b1` or something similar?

Comment: @Torxed the first part you quoted is for "Local version labels", which the version label scheme you quote is for Public version labels. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Valid Python *public version identifiers* all end in a digit:

> #### [Public version identifiers](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#version-scheme)
>
> The canonical public version identifiers MUST comply with the following scheme:
>
> ```
> [N!]N(.N)*[{a|b|rc}N][.postN][.devN]`
> ```

[Choosing a versioning scheme](https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#choosing-a-versioning-scheme) is much easier to read than the above PEP 440 description. Here also you'll notice that all patterns end in a digit.

Given that you don't want to increment to `v0.1.6`, you have the following alternate options:

- `v0.1.5.post1`
- `v0.1.5.dev1`

---

Side note: To reassign a tag that you already created to a different commit, use the `-f` flag on your `git tag` command and then try that push again.

Comment: Ended up reseting and making a new commit, but that's good to know. Thank you